# Change route in vue-router without reloading Components

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router4

I have a route in vue-router: `/items?page=1&rowsPerPage=25&sortBy=state&sortType=desc`

every Time i change one of the params (sortBy or page=2) i want to stay on the same site, without reloading the components i include. Currently everytime i update `router.replace({ ...router.currentRoute, query: params })` the page is reloaded.

How to avoid this? Is there any good pattern for this data-table use case?

Comment: The router should not behave this way, and it doesn't when I try it out. It is actually the other way round, you have to explicitly tell it to trigger a reload if you don't change the location (see [`force`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/RouteLocationOptions.html#Properties-force)). Is there a sandbox I (or someone else) could look at?

Comment: probably the problem is me using a layout pattern from https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/dynamic-vue-layout-components/ where i have router-view inside a router-view....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `router.push()` instead of `router.replace()`? It's been a while since I've worked with vue-router, but I've never used `replace` before. It could be that that solves it for you.

Worth giving a try.